# C# : Return Last node of linked list

Tags: c#, list, linked-list, stack, return

tryin to implement stack with linked list, have trouble in pop, the code

```
 public class MyItemType
    {
    ................
    }

 class MyStack
    {

        LinkedList<MyItemType> ourList = null;
        MyItemType top = null;

................

 public MyItemType Pop()
            {
                if (IsEmpty())
                {
                  return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    MyItemType temp = ourList.Last;  // <--- issue here
                    ourList.RemoveLast();
                    return temp;
                }
            }


................
```

}

error:
Error   2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.LinkedListNode' to 'Ex1.MyItemType'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do like this

```
ourList.Last.Value
```

[documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86397t7k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Dear, thanks a lot :) I am a newbie and documentation a bit of hard to understand. using some textbooks